# BAT script to delete a remote file

Tags: batch-file, samba, file-sharing, smb

I have a backup harddrive shared (SMB/CIFS) on my local Windows network. Now I need a windows BAT script that deletes some of the shared files in the backup drive. In Linux+bash it would be fairly simple but on a SMB/CIFS shared drive and using only batch scripting I could not find any solutions!

Comment: The files are accessible only via the share?

Comment: no, I can enable FTP access but I'd prefer to keep it disabled. However if you've got a solution involving FTP it would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a few things you can try.First to 'enable' deleting on the share you can first map the drive with `net use' :`
NET USE [driveletter:] \ComputerName\ShareName[\volume] [password | *] [/USER:[domainname]username] [/PERSISTENT:YES]`

And you probably will have access to the files with the DEL command.

If this does not work you'll need to execute the delete via SSH on the unix machine.For this you can use plink:
http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html
The documentation is descriptive enough I think..
And if this does not work too you'll need the heavy weapon -> Cygwin which is also can be used  via script to send commands via SSH